# AssetUrlSelector Dialog doesn't look like it should

Tags: 2010, asseturlselector

I can't make the AssetUrlSelector Dialog to look the same as in examples that I find throughout the internet.

I have simply put a AssetUrlSelector with some parameters just to try it out:

```
...
AssetUrlSelector assetPicker = new AssetUrlSelector();
assetPicker.ID = "Test_AssetPicker";
assetPicker.AssetPickerButtonVisible = true;
assetPicker.AllowExternalUrls = true;
assetPicker.IsUrlRequired = false;
assetPicker.PickerButtonText = "...";
assetPicker.UseImageAssetPicker = true;
assetPicker.DisplayLookInSection = true;
assetPicker.DefaultToLastUsedLocation = true;
assetPicker.DefaultOpenLocationUrl = "/PublishingImages/";
Controls.Add(assetPicker);
...
```

And I have tried toggling most properties to different values, especially "UseImageAssetPicker" and "DisplayLookInSection".
No matter what I set them to, the dialog still looks the same.

[image: Screenshot of the dialog]
Especially what I am missing is the actionbar, the one above the main-area that has the actions, so that I can upload new files while using the assetselectordialog.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this in ascx for a webpart and it is showing Upload button at top for me.

```
<CMS:AssetUrlSelector CssClass="MM_bbc-button"
                          ID="assetSelectedTemplate"                        
                          UseImageAssetPicker="false"
                          PickerButtonText="Select Letter Template"                          
                          MaxLength="512"
                          DecodeUrlPath="false"
                          AccessibilityName="<%$Resources:cms, asseteditimage_selectedimage_label%>"
                          runat="server"
                          AllowExternalUrls="false"
                          ValidateUrl="true"

                          AssetUrlTextBoxVisible="false"                          
                          OverrideDialogTitle="Choose MailMerge Template" 
                          OverrideDialogDescription="Select a Template"
                          ClientCallback="function(returnedUrl) {  assetLinkSelected(returnedUrl); }"               />
```

[image]